# Reading files instead of passing it as arguments

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have an executable program which only accepts two arguments "the file's opening command ./file and one other argument". What I want is to know how I can set a command which make the file read a file without passing it as argument on linux. I don't have the source code for the program but I've found this C-code on the internet and I think it might be similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
        // We assume argv[1] is a filename to open
        FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );

        /* fopen returns 0, the NULL pointer, on failure */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file\n" );
        }
        else 
        {
            int x;
            /* read one character at a time from file, stopping at EOF, which
               indicates the end of the file.  Note that the idiom of "assign
               to a variable, check the value" used below works because
               the assignment statement evaluates to the value assigned. */
            while  ( ( x = fgetc( file ) ) != EOF )
            {
                printf( "%c", x );
            }
            fclose( file );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$ alias executable='executable hidden_file'`

Comment: `$ ./my_program.out < my_data_file.txt` -- Will "pass" the file to the program via `std::cin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place commands into a file then pipe that file into your program.

```
./my_program.exe < my_commands.txt
```

The operating system will pass the file through `std::cin`.  So when you perform

```
std::string text_line;
std::getline(std::cin, text_line);
```

The input will come from "my_commands.txt" or what ever file was redirected to your program.

Comment: The problem is that the program only accepts one argument, so reading from a file will give me an error, is there anyway to read from that file and pass everything inside it as one argument?

Comment: Redirecting input does not involve parameters to a program.  Errors from reading a file is a topic for another question (after searching for examples).

Comment: is there anyway I can contact you, I have a question I want to ask, but I think it's off-topic for this site "It's related to the topic of this question"

Comment: I'm on LinkedIn and Wiselike.

Comment: I have added you to my connections on LInked-In